# Making a number using numbered cards

Tags: elementary-number-theory

You have 20 cards. Each card has unique number printed on it, from $1$ to $20$.

You can make a number using any number of cards (1 through 20 cards). For example, you can use three cards ('$9$', '$10$' and '$7$') to make a number, you place those three cards side by side, and then '$9107$' is made.

Now you use all those 20 cards and make any number of numbers. In an extreme case, you can make twenty numbers using one card for each number. In the other extreme case, you can make one number (with 31 digits) using all those 20 cards. Let's say you made N numbers. (Again, you should use all those twenty cards.)

Finally you add up all those N numbers in the normal way you would add decimal numbers.

> Question is - can the final sum be a number in the form of $10^k$ ($k$ is an integer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $10^k$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by three, but the sum of the digits of $1$ through $20$ is divisible by three.

Comment: So simple... Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect this was so simple.